# How to show non-printable characters in SWT a text widget

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, control-characters, styledtext

How is it possible to display non-printable characters in an SWT StyledText widget in a way it's done by Swing with an empty square?

To replace all occurrences with a symbol via regex in the source string can't be the solution because copy & paste with the original codepoint won't be possible anymore.

The best way might be to intercept the text rendering and replace them there, but that seems to open Pandora's box...

**Edit 1:**

The control characters, it's all about, are characters that are normally just skipped and not shown by the editor like HOP (U+0081)

Comment: How about extending [WhitespaceCharacterPainter](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.text.git/tree/org.eclipse.jface.text/src/org/eclipse/jface/text/WhitespaceCharacterPainter.java) (and use `StyledText` widget via `TextViewer`)?

Comment: Nice idea! I'll give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

For an E4 RCP application I have attached some code to start with.

Basically is uses the IEventBroker to add/remove the painter of the TextViewer by means of a button.

The StyledText can be obtained from

```
styledText = tv.getTextWidget();
```

as commented above

```
import org.eclipse.jface.text.WhitespaceCharacterPainter;
public class TheEditor{
    @Inject MPart thePart;
    private WhitespaceCharacterPainter whitespaceCharacterPainter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(Composite parent) {
            TextViewer tv = new TextViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL |SWT.H_SCROLL);
            whitespaceCharacterPainter = new  WhitespaceCharacterPainter(tv);
            tv.addPainter(whitespaceCharacterPainter);
            whitespaceCharacterPainter.deactivate(true);
    }

    @Inject
    @Optional
    public void updatePartByWSButton(@UIEventTopic(EventConstants.WHITE_CHARACTERS_STATUS) boolean newButtonStatus) {
        final MElementContainer<MUIElement>container = thePart.getParent();
        if (thePart.equals((MPart)container.getSelectedElement())){
            wsToolBarButtonStatus = newButtonStatus;
            if(wsToolBarButtonStatus){
              this.whitespaceCharacterPainter.paint(IPainter.CONFIGURATION);
            }
            else{
                whitespaceCharacterPainter.deactivate(true);
                tv.removePainter(whitespaceCharacterPainter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Handler Class

```
public class WhitespaceCharactersHandler {
    boolean status;
    @Execute
    public void execute(final MToolItem item, IEventBroker broker) {
        if (item.isSelected()){
            status = true;
        }
        else{
            status = false;
        }
        broker.post(EventConstants.WHITE_CHARACTERS_STATUS, status);
    }
}
```

Contants interface:

```
public interface EventConstants {
    String WHITE_CHARACTERS_STATUS = "WHITE-CHARACTERS-STATUS";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippets! Attaching a WhitespaceCharacterPainter is not really the point. it's how to draw non-printable chars that are normally just dropped in the view, like a HOP character (U+0081) - maybe via extending WhitespaceCharacterPainter in a way that has to be investigated...